# Is super-position actually an elementary-particle's third state?

Tags: superposition

Could it be said (as my question implies) that elementary particles (can) exist in three quite different states: wave, point-particle and superposition?

So, a wave or a point-particle could be 2 manifestations of an elementary particle in "our-macrocosmos dimension" and a superposition would be a third state of a particle in "quantum-microcosmos dimension"?

Does this makes any sense?

Comment: Superposition and waves go hand-in-hand. These two ideas aren't as separate as one may think.

Comment: But *any* state is a superposition of other states.  A 'point-particle' state is a superposition of, e.g., momentum eigenstates, energy eigenstates, etc.  A 'wave' state is a superposition of position eigenstates, etc. etc.  This is the nature of a vector space.